# Option aparecendo em textarea separado por vírgulas/linhas

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tentando fazer um pequeno formulário com base em HTML, CSS e JavaScript simples (sem JQuery).

Em uma das partes deste formulário, gostaria que qualquer `option` selecionada de um `select` apareça na `textarea` separada por vírgulas ou linhas. Além disso, a soma dos valores dos produtos selecionados devem aparecer no campo valor.

Até então, consegui fazer os valores aparecerem, contudo, não consigo fazer com que apareça tudo o que for clicado na área de texto. Eis o que fiz até agora:

```js
function M() {
  document.getElementById("produtos").value = document.getElementById("LstMesas").value;
}

function C() {
  document.getElementById("produtos").value = document.getElementById("LstCadeiras").value;
}

function calculaValor(formT) {

  var custo1 = document.getElementById("LstCadeiras");
  var cadeira = custo1.options[custo1.selectedIndex].value;

  var custo2 = document.getElementById("LstMesas");
  var mesa = custo2.options[custo2.selectedIndex].value;

  cadeira = parseFloat(cadeira);
  mesa = parseFloat(mesa);

  var total = cadeira + mesa;

  document.getElementById("valor").value = total;
}
```

```html
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="fsResEsq">
  <legend> Produtos</legend> <br/> Mesas:
  <select size="1" id="LstMesas" name="LstMesas" class="entDir" onchange="calculaValor()" , "M()">
    <option value="0" selected></option>

    <optgroup label="Diretor">
      <option value="500.00">Alfamob Sigma - R$500,00</option>
      <option value="360.00">Alfa Painel S40M136 - R$360,00</option>

    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Reunião">
      <option value="370.00">Alfamob Corp. semi-oval - R$370,00</option>

    </optgroup>
  </select><br/>

  <br/>Cadeiras:
  <select size="1" id="LstCadeiras" name="LstCadeiras" class="entDir" onchange="calculaValor()" , "C()">
    <option value="0" selected></option>

    <optgroup label="Secretária">
      <option value="190.00">Veneza 658 Fixa Couro - R$190,00</option>
      <option value="300.00">Turim Gir. Couro - R$300,00</option>
      <option value="200.00">Matriz Exp. Gir. Tecido - R$200,00</option>

    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Presidente">
      <option value="620.00">Firenze 560 Couro - R$620,00</option>
      <option value="800.00">Ipanema Prime Couro - R$800,00</option>

    </optgroup>

  </select><br/>

  <textarea readonly type="text" class="lstSel" id="produtos"></textarea><br/>
  <br/>Valor total: <input readonly type="text" name="TxtValor" class="shwValor" id="valor" />
  <br/><br/>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Na realidade, gostaria que na area de texto aparecesse qquer <option> que eu selecionar do meu <select>, e não os valores destes. Não sei se me fiz completamente claro...

Comment: o que você diz ser um option? Um option tem um value e um texto

Comment: Quis dizer somente que, na area de texto, gostaria que aparecesse o nome da opção (Ex: ao clicar em Alfamob(...), a mesma fosse para a area de texto). Ja o value deve ir para o Input Valor. Desta forma que você me descreveu, o que vai para a area de texto é o value dos produtos. Perdão se me faltou clareza. A resposta abaixo ilustra o que tentei dizer.

Comment: resumidamente, o que vc quer é o texto do option no textarea.

Comment: Exato! O texto do option ao clicar no mesmo. Uma vez mais, perdão se me faltou clareza na explicação.

Comment: tranquilo, estamos aqui para aprender e tirar duvidas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Separados por virgulas** com javascript puro

> Sem necessidade das funções `M()` e `C()` apenas usando a função `calculaValor()`

```js
function calculaValor() {

      var custo1 = document.getElementById("LstCadeiras");
      var cadeira = custo1.options[custo1.selectedIndex].value;

      var custo2 = document.getElementById("LstMesas");
      var mesa = custo2.options[custo2.selectedIndex].value;
      
var sel1 = document.getElementById("LstMesas");
var text1= sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].text;

var sel2 = document.getElementById("LstCadeiras");
var text2= sel2.options[sel2.selectedIndex].text;

text1 = text1.trim();
text2 = text2.trim()
      
    if (text1&&text2){
       strTotal = (text1 +","+ text2); 
    }else{
      strTotal = (text1 + text2);
    }


      cadeira = parseFloat(cadeira);
      mesa = parseFloat(mesa);

      var total = cadeira + mesa;
      
      document.getElementById("valor").value = total+",00";
      
      document.getElementById("produtos").value = strTotal;
    }
```

```html
<fieldset class="fsResEsq">
      <legend> Produtos</legend> <br/> Mesas:
      <select size="1" id="LstMesas" name="LstMesas" class="entDir" onchange="calculaValor()">
        <option value="0" selected></option>

        <optgroup label="Diretor">
          <option value="500.00">Alfamob Sigma - R$500,00</option>
          <option value="360.00">Alfa Painel S40M136 - R$360,00</option>

        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Reunião">
          <option value="370.00">Alfamob Corp. semi-oval - R$370,00</option>

        </optgroup>
      </select><br/>

      <br/>Cadeiras:
      <select size="1" id="LstCadeiras" name="LstCadeiras" class="entDir" onchange="calculaValor()">
        <option value="0" selected></option>

        <optgroup label="Secretária">
          <option value="190.00">Veneza 658 Fixa Couro - R$190,00</option>
          <option value="300.00">Turim Gir. Couro - R$300,00</option>
          <option value="200.00">Matriz Exp. Gir. Tecido - R$200,00</option>

        </optgroup>

        <optgroup label="Presidente">
          <option value="620.00">Firenze 560 Couro - R$620,00</option>
          <option value="800.00">Ipanema Prime Couro - R$800,00</option>

        </optgroup>

      </select><br/>

      <textarea readonly type="text" class="lstSel" id="produtos"></textarea><br/>
      <br/>Valor total: <input readonly type="text" name="TxtValor" class="shwValor" id="valor" />
      <br/><br/>
    </fieldset>
```

> Para separar por quebra de linha use \n ao inves de virgula nesse trecho de código

```
if (text1&&text2){
   strTotal = (text1 +"\n"+ text2); 
}else{
  strTotal = (text1 + text2);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e pelo código, Qualcuno! Fiz a correção de funções que você me sugeriu!

Comment: @WellingtonPimentel, ok, fiz mais algumas edições na resposta, inclusive apresentar valor com duas casa decimais

Answer (score 1):

Só porque você não tem jQuery não significa que você não possa usar queries, você ainda tem o `querySelector`.

Com `.fsResEsq option:checked`, você pode retornar todas as `option` selecionadas. Depois basta acessar seus atributos `value` para valor, ou `innerText`/`innerHTML` para seu texto.

```js
function calculaValor() {
  let opt = [...document.querySelectorAll('.fsResEsq option:checked')];

  let textos = opt.reduce((a, b) => b.innerText ? a.concat(b.innerText) : a, []);
  let valores = opt.reduce((a, b) => a + parseFloat(b.value), 0);

  document.getElementById('produtos').value = textos.join('\n');
  document.getElementById('valor').value = valores;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="fsResEsq">
  <legend> Produtos</legend> <br/> Mesas:
  <select size="1" id="LstMesas" name="LstMesas" class="entDir" onchange="calculaValor()">
    <option value="0" selected></option>

    <optgroup label="Diretor">
      <option value="500.00">Alfamob Sigma - R$500,00</option>
      <option value="360.00">Alfa Painel S40M136 - R$360,00</option>

    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Reunião">
      <option value="370.00">Alfamob Corp. semi-oval - R$370,00</option>

    </optgroup>
  </select><br/>

  <br/>Cadeiras:
  <select size="1" id="LstCadeiras" name="LstCadeiras" class="entDir" onchange="calculaValor()">
    <option value="0" selected></option>

    <optgroup label="Secretária">
      <option value="190.00">Veneza 658 Fixa Couro - R$190,00</option>
      <option value="300.00">Turim Gir. Couro - R$300,00</option>
      <option value="200.00">Matriz Exp. Gir. Tecido - R$200,00</option>

    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Presidente">
      <option value="620.00">Firenze 560 Couro - R$620,00</option>
      <option value="800.00">Ipanema Prime Couro - R$800,00</option>

    </optgroup>

  </select><br/>

  <textarea readonly type="text" class="lstSel" id="produtos"></textarea><br/>
  <br/>Valor total: <input readonly type="text" name="TxtValor" class="shwValor" id="valor" />
  <br/><br/>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: O seu script está funcional e bem proximo do que necessito! Muito obrigado!
Ah, e obrigado também pela explicação sobre jQuerry dentro do JavaScript pelo querySelector.

Answer (score 1):

Olá Wellington fiz um exemplo para você, porém seu código tem alguns pontos que listei:

> **1-** Você está chamando as funções de uma maneira errada assim **onchange="calculaValor()" , "C()"**, sendo que o correto é assim
>   **onchange="calculaValor();C()"**
>
> **2-** Você cria as funções **M()** e **C()** sendo que pode se criada apenas uma função obtendo os mesmos resultados o que torna o código melhor de se manter.
>
> **3-** Não sei se não postou o código todo, mas o parâmetro **formT** da função **calculaValor()** não está sendo utilizado.

```js
function MC() {
  var mesas = document.getElementById("LstMesas").options[document.getElementById('LstMesas').selectedIndex].innerText;;
  var cadei = document.getElementById("LstCadeiras").options[document.getElementById('LstCadeiras').selectedIndex].innerText; 
  var produ = document.getElementById("produtos");
  
  produ.value = mesas+" - "+cadei; // insere no textarea
}

function calculaValor() {

  var custo1 = document.getElementById("LstCadeiras");
  var cadeira = custo1.options[custo1.selectedIndex].value;

  var custo2 = document.getElementById("LstMesas");
  var mesa = custo2.options[custo2.selectedIndex].value;

  cadeira = parseFloat(cadeira);
  mesa = parseFloat(mesa);

  var total = cadeira + mesa;

  document.getElementById("valor").value = total+",00"; // coloca ,00
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="fsResEsq">
  <legend> Produtos</legend> <br/> Mesas:
  <select size="1" id="LstMesas" name="LstMesas" class="entDir" onchange="calculaValor();MC()">
    <option value="0" selected></option>

    <optgroup label="Diretor">
      <option value="500,00">Alfamob Sigma - R$500,00</option>
      <option value="360,00">Alfa Painel S40M136 - R$360,00</option>

    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Reunião">
      <option value="370,00">Alfamob Corp. semi-oval - R$370,00</option>

    </optgroup>
  </select><br/>

  <br/>Cadeiras:
  <select size="1" id="LstCadeiras" name="LstCadeiras" class="entDir" onchange="calculaValor();MC()">
    <option value="0" selected></option>

    <optgroup label="Secretária">
      <option value="190,00">Veneza 658 Fixa Couro - R$190,00</option>
      <option value="300,00">Turim Gir. Couro - R$300,00</option>
      <option value="200,00">Matriz Exp. Gir. Tecido - R$200,00</option>

    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Presidente">
      <option value="620,00">Firenze 560 Couro - R$620,00</option>
      <option value="800,00">Ipanema Prime Couro - R$800,00</option>

    </optgroup>

  </select><br/>

  <textarea readonly type="text" class="lstSel" id="produtos"></textarea><br/>
  <br/>Valor total: <input readonly type="text" name="TxtValor" class="shwValor" id="valor" />
  <br/><br/>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelas correções e pelo código, LeAndarde! O seu código está funcional e dentro do que necessito! Quanto ao ponto 3, essa "Id" faz referencia ao comando <form>, que não consta no fragmento que postei aqui... Obrigado uma vez mais!